# Nagios return status unknow

Tags: monitoring, status, nagios, tivoli

I install Nagios on CentOS to monitor some servers, and one of them is a TSM server.

I download a plugin written in bash when i execute it in command line it works.

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_tsm db -v6
db - database utilization 42%, OK
```

and the return code of the batch script is 0 ( from the command `echo $?` )

So the script work fine, and return 0 that mean a OK status in nagios, but the status still unknown, I really don't know why.

And i check logs in nagios, etc. It's not a problem of commands definition in commands.cfg or the declaration of service, because I copy the command that nagios send automatically every 5 min and the command works fine in command line, but still unknow status.

Definition of command:

define command{

```
    command_name check_tsm_v6

    command_line /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_tsm $ARG1$ -v6 $ARG2$ $ARG3$

    }
```

Service declaration :

define service{

```
    use generic-service 

    host_name        tsm-test

    service_description database utilization

    check_command check_tsm_v6!db!85!90
    }
```

And [here's](http://thobias.org/tsm/tsmmonitor/tsmmonitor) the bash script.

Comment: somebody to help me with this issue ?  :'(

Answer (score 0):

One thing that's caught me out in the past with Nagios scripts is user rights. When testing your script directly on the command line be sure to precede it with:

```
sudo -u nagios
```

So yours would be:

```
sudo -u nagios /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_tsm db -v6
```

This assumes that your nagios instance is being run by the nagios user, which is a fairly safe bet.

Good luck

Brad

Answer (score 0):

Try to use yum install sysstat -y command to download the package.

If it work that will a great. If you are facing still same please upload the complete error which is showing in browser?